# meaning of みんべえ

Tags: words, dialects, auxiliaries, modality, role-language

The full sentence comes from the story of [力太郎](http://life.ou.edu/stories/chikaratarou.html).

Here it is:

> 「ばあさん　や。この　あか　で　にんぎょう　を　つくって　みんべえ。」

I understand all the words except みんべえ, which I couldn't find in my dictionary.

Is this an old phrase?

Comment: Precisely for this reason, I rarely recommend children's stories for beginning learners.  They just use so many "imaginary dialectal phrases" for role language.  Look up みる and べい (**not** みん and べえ) separately in a better dictionary.  I'm sure you are already familiar with this みる, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

みんべえ is a collapsed pronunciation of みるべえ or みるべ.
る in verbs often contracts to ん in colloquial speech when followed by some words, eg:

> [何]{なに}[見]{み}て**る**のよ！　→  [何]{なに}[見]{み}て**ん**のよ！
>   バカなことす**る**なよ。 → バカなことす**ん**なよ。

みる here is a subsidiary verb (補助動詞) and means "try doing~~".

The べえ is a prolonged べ.   べ is a sentence-final particle (終助詞) mainly used in Tohoku dialect, meaning ～(だ)ろう, ～(で)しょう, ～(し)よう, ～(し)ましょう. Here it's used as old man's speech (老人語), a kind of role language (役割語) in fiction.

Examples of the use of べ:

> いく**べ**。 ≂ 行こう。 / 行きましょう。
>   んだ**べ**。 ≂ そうだろう。 / そうでしょう。
>   どうすん**べ**。/ どうすっ**べ**。 （< どうす**る**べ）≂ どうしよう？ / どうしましょう。

So the phrase in your example can be rephrased:

> 「つくってみんべえ。」 ≂ 「つくってみよう。 / つくってみましょう。」
>   "Let's try making~"

Answer (score 1):

I think it's old or a different dialect for みよう。

I will explain my reasoning as follows.

As said by @l'électeur, let's break みんべえ　up into みん　and べい　instead.

みん will break up into みる and ん.

> みる (in this case, helps indicate to "try making")
>
> +
>
> ん　(ねえ, which makes this 「見ん（見む ）」 in Tohoku dialect according to @Chocolate)
>
> +
>
> べい（[which can indicate invitation)](http://jisho.org/search/bei) = みんべい

In Tohoku dialect, 「みんべい」 is the contracted form of 「見る + べ」, meaning「みよう」。

> ばあさんや。この あか で にんぎょう を つくって **みよう**。
>
> ”Old woman. **Let's try and make** a doll from this dirt."

[Story](http://life.ou.edu/stories/chikaratarou.html)

Comment: No explanation of べい?　Or the ん?

Comment: @l'électeur added. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: `ん（negative verb ending..` -- その「ん」は、否定の「ん」じゃないですね・・

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ そう！「ぬ」の意味、多分。

Comment: 東北弁の「べ」と一緒に使うのなら、「ぬ」は「ねぇ」になるのでは・・？「見ねぇべ」って…。「する+べ」は「すんべ/すっべ」、「やる+べ」は「やんべ/やっべ」になって、「しない+べ」は「しねぇべ」、「やらない+べ」は「やらねぇべ/やんねぇべ」になるんだし・・

Comment: でも、「みる＋ん」は　「みませんか」じゃないの？だから「みよう」の意味ですね。

Comment: ^ 違うと思います・・・。 「みる＋ん」は「みませんか」ではありません。「見る＋ん(= **negative ぬ** )」 is 「見ん（見**ぬ** ）」 and means「見ない」. 「見る＋ん(= **volitional む** )」 is 「見ん（見**む** ）」 and means 「見よう / 見るだろう」. BUT in
 Tohoku dialect 「見る＋negative ぬ+べ」 is 「み**ねえ**べ」 and means 「見ないだろう」.  In Tohoku dialect, 「み**ん**べ」 is the contracted form of 「見**る** + べ」 (not 見る+negativeぬ+べ), meaning 「みよう」.

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ なるほど！答えを直しました。

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone I think what ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ explained was that because this sentence is spoken in Tohoku dialect, you should only consider its grammar in this case. According to [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E5%8C%97%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E6.96.87.E6.B3.95), the Tohoku べ attaches to the **終止形** (＝みる) but is changed to み**ん** due to 撥音化＝"ん-ification". In ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ's answer it's called "contraction".

Comment: うまく説明できなくてすみません・・・

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ 大丈夫です。ありがとう＾＿＾